# Difference between RFC 2986 & RFC 4211 and which one is a spec for Certificate Signing Requests?

Tags: security, certificate, public-key-encryption, rfc, csr

The abstract for [RFC 4211](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4211) seems to say that the RFC is meant to be a spec for CRMF (which I understand to be a protocol for transmitting a CSR), while [RFC 2986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2986) specs out the `CertificationRequest` information type, which seems also be a CSR.

What is CRMF, how does it relate to a CSR, and which RFC ultimately specs out a CSR?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CRMF is one way to request a certificate [SCEP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nourse-scep-23) is another, and so is [ACME](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8555.txt).

The Rfc 2986 specifies PKCS#10, which is what a CSR is. Most protocols transmit PKCS#10 plus some more info (for instance authentication ands other metadata).